# iOS: Problem with the NSManagedObjectContext / NSFetchRequest / NSEntityDescription

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have an error message **'** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' **-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'**

The problem is on the **fetchedObjects**.

This is because it tries to add a value that is nil to an NSArray. What I don't understand, is why there is that empty value.

For info: The table is the name of the table of my sqlite and the label is just a field of my table.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getLabel:(NSString *)label fromTable:(NSString *)table 
{
    NSMutableArray * ret = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:table
                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    Class theClass = NSClassFromString(table);
    id info = [[theClass alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    for (info in fetchedObjects)
    {
        [ret addObject:[info valueForKey: label]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

*Good initialization:*
[image]

*Bad initialization:*
[image]

Do you have any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing surprising, that just now allocated object have empty fields.

Comment: You should always check if an object is nil before adding it to an array or dictionary. 

There is not enough info there to understand why [info valueForKey: label] is nil. We would need to see the piece of code that creates your managed object and stores it in the database. We would also need to know the value of 'label'.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I didn't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: @Dimitar08 I know that I have to check the nil, but my problem is not to avoid the nil, but to explain it. I don't want to hide the dust under the carpet... I will put more information in the ticket if it can help.

Comment: After taking a closer look at the code, Cy-4AH is correct. Your code is creating a new managed object. Makes sense that none of the fields on the object would be populated with data at this point.

Comment: @Dimitar08 For info, I updated my ticket, I added For info: The table is the name of the table of my sqlite and the label is just a field of my table. I confirm you that at this point, I have some fields in my object. The table contains the fields label1, label2, label3, etc.... And I give it the parameter label that is "label1", that is a field in the table. It always worked until today, I don't understand why it suddenly accumulate some nil datas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common error. I think you should have a look at your line:

```
id info = [[theClass alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Look here if you want to have more info: [Use NSManagedObject class without initWithEntity:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139033/use-nsmanagedobject-class-without-initwithentity)

You should insertIntoManagedObjectContect:nil

Comment: Ohh thank you very much, I was looking everywhere, and it was so simple! Many thanks, you save my week :D (it added lines and lines just because of that. It is very strange that for initializing a variable, I need to use an insertIntoMAnagedObjectContext..., because I tried the simple initWithEntity: and it didn't work)

Comment: I think he need just `for (id info in fetchedObjects)` without any `insertIntoManagedObjectContect`